# decorators with the same name

Tags: design-patterns, decorator, uml

well, I'm going to be direct, 
it's about the decorator pattern
you'll see, i made this graph to exemplify the situation

i have two classes (lets say: CAR and VAN) which are  related as the graph says, and i need

to freely combine two decorator classes ..
but i have one decorator that is applicable just for one of them
since these decorators add specific functionality but this functionality is essentially the

same for the correspondent class..

can I name them just the same?

following the same graph
i tried to inherit VAN from CAR. that way they both has the same decorators.. but as ia said

VAN  can't have liquefied gas"

so my question remains..
can i name they both decorator the same?

thanks a lot in advance

gmocamilo

http://www.depositodeimagenes.com/images/h2bpM.jpg

pd. im sorry but the system doesn't allow me upload figures

Comment: thw best source about this pattern came from http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/decorator            but not there or elsewhere i find this situation

Answer (score 1):

Having two classes do the same thing and have the same name is generally a bad practice, like all code duplication. The FourWheelDrive decorator should be directly descending from Vehicle and accept a Vehicle as decoratee. The LiquidGas decorator can descend from SimpleCar and accept a SimpleCar as decoratee, if you want to restrict its use to SimpleCar:

```
class LiquidGasDecorator extends Vehicle
{
   private SimpleCar simplecar_;
   public LiquidGasDecorator(SimpleCar simplecar)
   {
     simplecar_ = simplecar;
   }
}

Vehicle fourwheelvan = new FourWheelDriveDecorator(new Van());
Vehicle fourwheelcarwithlpg = new LiquidGasDecorator(new FourWheelDriveDecorator(new SimpleCar)));
```

Comment: Ozan
you are totally right!
i was lost in the details of the child classes
i dont know how i missed this obvious arrangement 
thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I think you should create a class Car, then you create a class CarDecorator. From CarDecorator you inherit with classes that contain the attributes that you want.

That way When you create the car you use classes from the CarDecorator to add various "parts" to your car and since you are inheriting from CarDecorator you can cascade attributes by having one constructor that takes a CarDecorator as argument:

E.g.

```
Car* van = new Car( new FourWheelDrive() );
```

and

```
Car* car = new Car( new FourWheelDrive( new LiquidGas() ) );
```

You could of course put FourWheelDrive in the base class Car from the start but by doing so if you ever want to have a three wheel car in the future you would have to change the base class with all what that means. The above approach allows you to keep the base class untouched.

Comment: Anders..
i find this just a little complicated, it's my fault 'cause i ought to mention i can't alter the base class  
but i'm taking it account 
thank you so much for your contribution!